# how to calculate proportional ratio

Tags: c#, math

First of all pardon me to raise this question here (not sure). Not good in maths so need help from others to understand how to calculate.

I have to calculate proportional ratio score. For doing that i am taking two input values

```
ValueA = 3
ValueB = 344.
```

To find the percentage of the proportional ratio ((ValueB-ValueA)/ValueA )*100)

that formula gives me the score 11366.6.

Now i have to match with proportional percentage against with following table,
 no idea how to match with percentage

for example the score comes around 43.12 % then i will pick the value 5 (>40 -50)

```
% Ratio       Score
    0           0
    ≤10         1
    >10 – 20    2
    >20 – 30    3
    >30 – 40    4
    >40 – 50    5
    >50 – 60    6
    >60 – 70    7
    >70 – 80    8
    >80 – 90    9
    >90 – 100   10
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is grossly off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your formula is of (as you can see by the 11366.6 percentage) - it should be

```
100.0*(ValueB-ValueA)/(double)ValueB
```

this will give you values in between 0 and 100 percent if `ValueB` is always bigger than `ValueA` (if not use):

```
100.0*Math.Abs(ValueB - ValueA)/(double)Math.Max(ValueA, ValueB)
```

based on the table your score should than be simply:

```
var score = (int)Math.Ceiling(percentage / 10.0)
```

Comment: thanks Carsten but i noticed if i used Value A= 250 and Value B = 301 the score is showing 2 but it should be three right. Actual percentage ratio is 20.4

Comment: well (301-250)/301 is about 0.17 so the 2 seems quite right to me  - I have no clue how you end up with 20.4 here

Answer (score 1):

You should swap value a and value b of you get percentages bigger than 100. By the way, finding the proportional value is not unique and the formula you have provided is one way to do that. I guess Valuea/valueb is also a possibility for example.